# Expanding rows only when button clicked

Tags: javascript

In my table i have button , when its clicked it should expanding rows and this how i navigated in my Javascripts, but `my problem is when i clicked everywhere in table it will expandig rows`, but i want rows expanded, when **only** button get clicked.

My question is how should i navigate in my JavaScript?!

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "",
    data: ,
    success: function (result) {
        $("#DIV").html('');
        var rows = "";
  $.each(result, function (i, e) {

      rows += '<tr class="RMAJS">';
      rows += '<td id="varnummer" name="varnummer">' + e.varnummer + '</td>';
      rows += '<td id="Beskrivelse" name="Beskrivelse">' + e.Beskrivelse + '</td>';

      rows += '<td><button type="submit" class="sendRMA">Anmod om RMA</button></td>';

      rows += '</tr>';

      rows += '<tr style="display:none;" class="section">';
      rows += '<td>test</td>'
      rows += '</tr>';

 }); //End of foreach Loop

        $('#ResultProduct').append(rows);

    }
})
```

HTML:

```
   <table class="table">
      <thead>
         <tr>
          <th>Varenummer</th>
          <th>Beskrivelse</th>
          <th></th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
  <tbody id="ResultProduct">
    <tr class="RMAJS">
       <td id="varnummer" name="varnummer">61A6MAT3</td>
       <td id="Beskrivelse" name="Beskrivelse">Lenovo T24</td>
       <td><button type="submit" class="sendRMA">Anmod om RMA</button></td>
    </tr>
   <tr style="display:none;" class="section">
    <td>test</td>
   </tr>

 <tr class="RMAJS">
           <td id="varnummer" name="varnummer">AMAT3</td>
           <td id="Beskrivelse" name="Beskrivelse">Dell</td>
           <td><button type="submit" class="sendRMA">Anmod om RMA</button></td>
  </tr>  
  <tr style="display:none;" class="section">
        <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
    </table>
```

And here 3 Javascripts i'll come up with:

- The first one will expand rows not only when button clicked, but it will also expand rows when i clicked everywhere in table

  ```
  $('#ResultProduct').on("click", ".RMAJS", function () {
      $(this).next('.section').toggle("slow");  });
  ```
- The Second & Third not going  to expanding rows when i clicked on button:

  ```
  $('.sendRMA').on("click", function () {
      $(this).next('.section').toggle("slow");
  });

  $('.RMAJS').on("click", ".sendRMA", function () {
      $(this).next('.section').toggle("slow");
  });
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) you should not use next as next will be the next element, but your section is next to tr not next to td, so you will have to first find the tr and then next section.

```
$('.sendRMA').on("click", function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').next('.section').toggle("slow");
});
```

```js
$('.sendRMA').on("click", function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').next('.section').toggle("slow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Varenummer</th>
      <th>Beskrivelse</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="ResultProduct">
    <tr class="RMAJS">
      <td id="varnummer" name="varnummer">61A6MAT3</td>
      <td id="Beskrivelse" name="Beskrivelse">Lenovo T24</td>
      <td><button type="submit" class="sendRMA">Anmod om RMA</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none;" class="section">
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="RMAJS">
      <td id="varnummer" name="varnummer">AMAT3</td>
      <td id="Beskrivelse" name="Beskrivelse">Dell</td>
      <td><button type="submit" class="sendRMA">Anmod om RMA</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none;" class="section">
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I just tried but no luck - its not going to expanding rows. $('.sendRMA').on("click", function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').next('.section').toggle("slow");
});

Comment: @seems like your code is conflicting with other one,  make sure following things 1st bind this event after you load whole table 2nd) remove all other events

Comment: When i run the code in console in browser and than click on button it will display alert , but when its run from the code it will not.         $('button.sendRMA').on("click", function () {
          
            alert("test");
        });

Comment: @TheFirst because you are loading the tables dynamically, wrap this event in function and call that function after your `$('#ResultProduct').append(rows);`